# Reading large Number response from HTTPURLConnection as String

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, atg

Need help on Httpurlconnection android response as string, 
I am working with ATG Portal, Here I am facing big Problem on JSON Response.

ATG REST API will return a Session Confirmation Number, This Number is large in Size and Long cannot hold the value of it, the Number is getting Rounded When it received.

> Is there any way to receive the response as string using HttpURLconnection?

Here is the running code

```
 String url = "http://IP:Port/rest/model/atg/rest/SessionConfirmationActor/getSessionConfirmationNumber";
        HttpURLConnection httpcon;
        StringBuilder response  = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            //Connect
            httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(url).openConnection()));
            httpcon.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpcon.setReadTimeout(10000); // millis
            httpcon.setConnectTimeout(15000); // millis
            httpcon.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");
            httpcon.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            httpcon.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");
            httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
            httpcon.connect();
            if (httpcon.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                InputStream stream = httpcon.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(stream );
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(isReader );
                String strLine = null;
                while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response.append(strLine);
                    Log.v("-------------------------------LoginActivity", String.valueOf(response));
                }
                input.close();
            }
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
            String date = obj.getString("sessionConfirmationNumber");
            httpcon.disconnect();
            Log.v("-------------------------------LoginActivity", date);

        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Hello";
    }
```

I have faced same issue with webPortal and I have solved using XMLhttpconnection method Please help.....!

Comment: Firstly I believe the `Content-Type` should be set to `application\json`.  Secondly, have you tried using a `java.math.BigInteger`?

Comment: I have Tried, I am getting 409 conflict error, From Android and the number is getting changed on each call, Basically the session confirmation number should not get changed for a certain period(session time out)

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. Is the issue that you cannot store the `sessionConfirmationNumber` in a `long`? If so, the solution is to treat it as a `String`, not a number. Secondly, the session confirmation number is a little misnamed. It is *not* the session id - that is represented as a JSESSIONID cookie. It is a *per-request* token - each request will return you a new value, and you are expected to send the latest value back in the subsequent request.

Comment: Hey, Thanks the is issue has been fixed, clear cookie helped!